# Dart function argument can't be assigned even though it is the same type

Tags: dart

I have this code:

```dart
void baz(String s) {
}

void bar<T>(T val, void Function(T) encode) {
}

void foo() {
  (<String>(val) => bar<String>(val, baz))("foo");
}
```

However it gives this error:

> The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)'. *dart(argument_type_not_assignable)*

A confusing error to say the least! What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart type parameters are kind of strange since you can use reserved keywords and types as names for these parameters. In this case, `<String>(val) => ...` is actually using `String` as the name of a type argument in the context of the closure, conflicting with the class `String` in `dart:core`. If you drop the type argument to your closure in `foo`, this code should work and the type of `val` in `bar` will still be `String`. If you want to be sure, you can explicitly type the `val` parameter in the closure:

```dart
void foo() {
  ((String val) => bar<String>(val, baz))("foo");
}
```

Also, the type parameter to `bar` can be left out as type inference will be able to infer the type `T` is `String`:

```dart
void foo() {
  ((String val) => bar(val, baz))("foo");
}
```